# Getting Values from own PickerView

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, timer, picker

I'm new to Swift and I'm currently developing my own Timer Application for practice purposes. (I do it without storyboard)

Now I have the Problem that i made a View called "TimePickerView" (Code below), where I created my own Picker. Then I use that TimePickerView in another part of my Application  with other Views (in a View). In that View I want to pick my time but I don't know how i can get the Values of the Picker (The Picker works by the way)

This is my TimePickerView

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimePickerView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTimeIndexSecond = 0
    @State private var selectedTimeIndexMinutes = 0
    
    @State private var seconds : [Int] = Array(0...59)
    @State private var minutes : [Int] = Array(0...59)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            
            Text("Select Your Time")
            
            HStack{
                                
                //minutes-Picker
                Picker("select time", selection: $selectedTimeIndexMinutes, content: {
                    
                    ForEach(0..<minutes.count, content: {
                        index in
                        Text("\(minutes[index]) min").tag(index)
                    })
                    
                })
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 120)
                .clipped()
                
                
                //seconds-Picker
                Picker("select time", selection: $selectedTimeIndexSecond, content: {
                    
                    ForEach(0..<seconds.count, content: {
                        index in
                        Text("\(seconds[index]) sec").tag(index)
                    })
                })
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 120)
                .clipped()
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            
            Text("You picked the time")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.title2)
                .padding()
            
            
            
            Text("\(minutes[selectedTimeIndexMinutes]) min : \(seconds[selectedTimeIndexSecond]) sec")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .padding(.top, -14.0)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func getValues() -> (Int, Int) {
        return (self.minutes[selectedTimeIndexMinutes] ,self.seconds[selectedTimeIndexSecond])
    }
    
}
```

and that is the View I want to use my Picker, but I don't know how I get those values from the Picker:

```
struct SetTimerView: View {
    
    @State var timepicker = TimePickerView()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            
            VStack{
                
                //Select the time
                timepicker
                
                //Timer variables (This doesn't work)
                var timerTime = timepicker.getValues()
                var minutes = timerTime.0
                var seconds = timerTime.1
                
                Spacer()
                
                let valid : Bool = isValid(timerTime: minutes+seconds)
                
                //Confirm the time
                NavigationLink(
                    destination:
                        getRightView(
                            validBool: valid,
                            timerTime: minutes*60 + seconds),
                    label: {
                        ConfirmButtonView(buttonText: "Confirm")
                    });
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func isValid(timerTime : Int) -> Bool {
        if (timerTime == 0) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    
    
    @ViewBuilder func getRightView(validBool : Bool, timerTime : Int) -> some View{
        if (validBool == true) {
            TimerView(userTime: CGFloat(timerTime), name: "David", isActive: true)
        } else {
            UnvalidTimeView()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are using SwiftUI, not plain swift. You should add that tag to your question.

Comment: the selectedTimeIndexMinutes/Seconds is the index in the "list" of the values which are selected in the moment - but my question is how do I get those values in my SetTimerView (minutes[selectedTimeIndexMinutes] and seconds[selectedTimeIndexSeconds])? @Sh_Khan

Comment: A `View` shouldn't be an `@State`. If you want the values make the current `seconds` and `minutes` `@Binding` and create `@State` variables in the `SetTimerView`. Put in the `body` something like this `TimePickerView(minutes: $minutes, seconds: $seconds)`

Comment: @loremipsum and how can i set the `@State` variable with my current second/minute?

Comment: Current as in current time or current from an object from storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think main problem is misunderstanding conceptions between data and views.

At first you need a model witch will override your data (create it in separate swift file):

```
import Foundation

class Time: ObservableObject {
@Published var selectedTimeIndexMinutes: Int = 0
@Published var selectedTimeIndexSecond: Int = 0
}
```

Pay attention on `ObservableObject` so that swiftUI can easily detect changes to it that trigger any active views to redraw.

Next I try to change the value of the model in the view

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimePickerView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var timeData: Time

@State private var seconds : [Int] = Array(0...59)
@State private var minutes : [Int] = Array(0...59)

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        
        
        Text("Select Your Time")
        
        HStack{
                            
            //minutes-Picker
            Picker("select time", selection: $timeData.selectedTimeIndexMinutes, content: {
                
                ForEach(0..<minutes.count, content: {
                    index in
                    Text("\(minutes[index]) min").tag(index)
                })
                
            })
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 120)
            .clipped()
            
            //seconds-Picker
            Picker("select time", selection: $timeData.selectedTimeIndexSecond, content: {

                ForEach(0..<seconds.count, content: {
                    index in
                    Text("\(seconds[index]) sec").tag(index)
                })
            })
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 120)
            .clipped()

            Spacer()
            
        }
        
        Text("You picked the time")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .font(.title2)
            .padding()
        
        Text("\(timeData.selectedTimeIndexMinutes) min : \(timeData.selectedTimeIndexSecond) sec")
            .font(.title)
            .bold()
            .padding(.top, -14.0)
        
    }
    
}

}

struct TimePickerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
    TimePickerView()
        .environmentObject(Time())
 }
}
```

Like you can see I don't using `@Blinding`, instead of it I connecting our Model with a View

On the next view I can see changes, I created a new one because your example have view that don't indicated here...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReuseDataFromPicker: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var timeData: Time
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
    
            Text("You selected")
            Text("\(timeData.selectedTimeIndexMinutes) min and \(timeData.selectedTimeIndexSecond) sec")
            
        }
    }
}

struct ReuseDataFromPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReuseDataFromPicker()
            .environmentObject(Time())
    }
}
```

And collect all in a Content View

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            TimePickerView()
                .tabItem {Label("Set Timer", systemImage: "clock.arrow.2.circlepath")}
            
            ReuseDataFromPicker()
                .tabItem {Label("Show Timer", systemImage: "hourglass")}
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(Time())

    }
}
```

Like that you can easily change or reuse your data on any other views

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!